# Fatal error: Class 'CI_Config' not found in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/handyman/system/core/Common.php on line 196

Tags: codeigniter

Can anyone help me with the error in title please?

The website works fine on Windows and Linux systems, but not on Macs.

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Error
>
> Message: Class 'CI_Config' not found
>
> Filename: core/Common.php
>
> Line Number: 196
>
> Backtrace:

Comment: Please give an example of your code so that we can understand further.

Comment: Looks like an XAMPP config issue.